# Sending a request from one WSDL to another WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, xslt, soap, wsdl

I want to know is it possible to send a request from one wsdl to another wsdl. If yes, then how do I do that?

The flow will be :

I want to expose a wsdl using switchyard say wsdl-1 which might have 100 parameters, with create, get, delete and set request.
I want a XSLT which will take the request from wsdl-1 and I will pick only few parameters and will ignore the other remaining parameter.
Now with the picked parameters in XSLT, I want to send another request to my other wsdl say wsdl-2 which will perform its task.

[image]

I am not sure how do I do this and need some guidance . Please let me if the question is not clear from my end.

**EDIT :**
Adding the exact flow architecture which I am looking for. I want to know how would I communication with WSDL Country 1 and my SIM WSDL.

I want to know whether is it possible or not (communication between two wsdls).

Please let know if you need more explanation.

[image]

Comment: You can't send requests to a WSDL and have it perform some business logic. Your question does not make any sense. Please rephrase it otherwise you won't get any answers and your question is sure to be closed.

Comment: @Bogdan : Please see the updated image and let me know if this can be done or not. If yes how do I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the link below, it provids detailed expalianation on your all the above questions :

https://developer.jboss.org/message/910909#910909